# Should I write all my route handling code in a try-catch block?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is this good use of try…catch, or should I write everything in try block? I am trying to prevent nested try…catch blocks.

```js
    router.post('/refresh', async (req, res) => {
        const refreshToken = req.body.token;
        let decoded;

        try {
            decoded = jwt.verify(
                refreshToken,
                process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
            );
        } catch(error) {
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        }

        // … use decoded variable here
    });
```

Comment: Broadly speaking, `try..catch` blocks should be as narrow, small and specific as possible. Since you `return` inside the `catch`, you can safely rely on anything after only running if the `try` was successful.

Comment: is predefining variable on top level to use after `try…catch` common practice?

Comment: Indeed, thats a good use case

Comment: @kernelc you have to, if you define it inside it will be undefined outside because it would be out of scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll never need to nest `try/catches` -  a `catch()` will catch all errors underneath it.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Specifically:

> The try...catch statement marks **a block of statements** to try and specifies a response should an exception be thrown.

However if you're unsure that `refreshToken` will exist (it's a good example not to trust web browsers), you can add it to the block you're catching errors in:

```
    router.post('/refresh', async (req, res) => {
        let decoded;

        try {
            const refreshToken = req?.body?.token;
            if ( ! token ) {
                 throw new Error('Token not supplied!')
            }
            decoded = jwt.verify(
                refreshToken,
                process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
            );
        } catch(error) {
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        }

        // … use decoded variable here
    });
```

Comment: `let` has block scope, then to access variable I have to predefine it on top level, is it common practice?

Comment: You don't have to define refreshToken outside the block, since you only need `refreshToken` once inside the block - in fact you can make it a constant. I've edited the code above accordingly.